# Getting push notifications on insert although the sendNotifications parameter is false

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

i'm trying to insert an event to Google calendar WITHOUT getting a push notification back in the minute i insert the event.i only want to receive the push notifications, into my system, when a change is made in the google calendar itself.

i always get push notifications when i insert a new event from my system into google calendar.
the "sendNotifications" is ignored completly.
not only the "sendNotifications" is supposed to be "false" as default but i still get push notification when i insert a new event.
also tried to set it to "false" using the "optparams" array but it is ignored by google calendar and i always get a push notification on the event i just inserted, in the minute i insert the event.

this is the code:

```
$optParams['sendNotifications'] = false;
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert($user->google_cal_id_c, $event,$optParams);
```

Why am i getting a push notification although the "insert" function supposed to set the "sendNotifications" as false anyhow?
and why is it ignored?

Comment: When you set up a push notification on events(with events.watch) resource, then calendar API notifies when ever there is change in the resource. Even inserting an event will be notified(As this event counts as resource change). When send notifications is set to "false", then email notification will not be send to the attendees in the calendar invite. Both notifications are not related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#api-events) on the notification messages you can receive when using push notifications with the Google Calendar API.

Comment: i'm having a HUGE multithreading problem because of this instant Push notification message i get when i add a new meeting to the calendar from my system. because after i add the meeting to the calendar, from my system, i need to do other updates on the meeting in my system, but the notification i receive instantly from the calendar inteferes in the middle. so you are saying i can't configure the calendar to send push notification only when the change was done in the calendar interface? is there a way to set a dalay of 10 seconds for the push notification to arrive? this will solve the problem.